# Questions about select()

Tags: sockets, select, tcp, server

Considering the following class method:

```
void TCPServer::listenWithTimeout() {
  fd_set descrSet;
  struct timeval timeout = {1, 0};
  while (listeningThread.active) {
    std::cout << "TCP Server thread is listening..." << std::endl;
    FD_ZERO(&descrSet);
    FD_SET(mySocketFD, &descrSet);
    int descrAmount = select(mySocketFD + 1, &descrSet, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (descrAmount > 0) {
      assert(FD_ISSET(mySocketFD, &descrSet));
      int threadIndx = findAvailableThread();
      if (threadIndx < 0) {
        std::cout << "Connection not accepted: no threads available..." << std::endl;
      } else {
        joinThread(threadIndx);
        int newSocketFD = accept(mySocketFD, (struct sockaddr *) &mySocket, &clieAddrssLen);
        std::cout << "TCP Client connected..." << std::endl;
        connectionThreads[threadIndx].thread = std::thread(TCPServer::startTCPConnectionWithException, std::ref(*this), threadIndx, newSocketFD);
        connectionThreads[threadIndx].active = true;
      }
    }
  }
  std::cout << "TCP Server thread is terminating..." << std::endl;
}
```

Here are some question:

1. when there are not available threads (`findAvailableThreads()` returns `-1`), is it a normal behaviour that `select()` doesn't wait its timeout and so the `while` loop iterates really fast until a new thread is available?
2. if yes, how could I avoid these really fast iterations? Instead of using something like a simple `sleep()` at line 13 inside the `if` branch, is there a way to let `select()` restore its timeout? Or even, is there a way to completely reject the incoming connection pending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when there are not available threads (findAvailableThreads() returns -1), is it a normal behaviour that select() doesn't wait its timeout and so the while loop iterates really fast until a new thread is available?

Yes, because under that condition, you are not calling `accept()`, so you are not changing the listening socket's state. It will remain in a readable state as long as it has a client connection waiting to be `accept()`'ed.

> if yes, how could I avoid these really fast iterations?

Call `accept()` before checking for an available thread. If no thread is available, close the accepted connection.

> Instead of using something like a simple sleep() at line 13, inside the if branch, is there a way to let select() restore its timeout?

The only way is to `accept()` the connection that put the listening socket into a readable state, so it has a chance to go back to a non-readable state.  The timeout will not apply again until the socket is no longer in a readable state.

> Or even, is there a way to completely reject the incoming connection pending?

The only way is to `accept()` it first, then you can `close()` it if needed.

Try this:

```
void TCPServer::listenWithTimeout() {
    fd_set descrSet;
    while (listeningThread.active) {
        std::cout << "TCP Server thread is listening..." << std::endl;
        FD_ZERO(&descrSet);
        FD_SET(mySocketFD, &descrSet);
        struct timeval timeout = {1, 0};
        int descrAmount = select(mySocketFD + 1, &descrSet, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (descrAmount > 0) {
            assert(FD_ISSET(mySocketFD, &descrSet));
            int newSocketFD = accept(mySocketFD, (struct sockaddr *) &mySocket, &clieAddrssLen);
            if (newSocketFD != -1) {
                int threadIndx = findAvailableThread();
                if (threadIndx < 0) {
                    close(newSocketFD);
                    std::cout << "Connection not accepted: no threads available..." << std::endl;
                } else {
                    joinThread(threadIndx);
                    std::cout << "TCP Client connected..." << std::endl;
                    connectionThreads[threadIndx].thread = std::thread(TCPServer::startTCPConnectionWithException, std::ref(*this), threadIndx, newSocketFD);
                    connectionThreads[threadIndx].active = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "TCP Server thread is terminating..." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Considering `int listen(int s, int backlog)`, instead of accepting and closing right away after the connection, limiting the `backlog` argument could be an alternative solution?

Comment: Another potential way to handle it would be not to include the accept-socket in your `descrSet` if you know that you don't currently have any threads available to handle the next incoming connection -- that would prevent your `select()` call from returning when you can't handle the new connection anyway.  (Of course, you'd need to have some way to wake up from `select()` when a thread becomes available, so that you can start watching the accept-socket again at that time)